# What is the ratio of the number of the leaves to the total number of nodes in a random tree?

Tags: random, trees

I generate the random trees using a Galton-Watson process in the following way:

- The maximum number of Generation is G=4
- The minimum and the maximum number of branchings are zero and five (0-5) respectively.
- Having zero branching is allowed only after $G \geq 2$. Otherwise, there is a high probability that I will end up with trees with only one node.
- The nodes that have no branching either in the last generation (G=4) or in the inner generations (G<4) are called heminodes and the sum of all these nodes is called $\mathcal{H}$
- The total number of nodes in each random tree is called $\mathcal{N}$

I do the above simulation for $10^6$ times, The following is the probability distribution of $R= \frac{\mathcal{H}}{\mathcal{N}}$.

[The probability distribution of $R= \frac{\mathcal{H}}{\mathcal{N}}$ (click to see the figure please)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izUoC.jpg)

Is there any mathematical theory that could give the distribution for any given number of generations and branching?

For the importance of this ratio, I recommend having a look at our recent paper. ["Emergent stochastic oscillations and signal detection in tree networks of excitable elements"](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-04193-8) https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-04193-8

Answer (score 0):

Ration distribution is a non-trivial problem for two random variables with unknown distributions. Though there are a lot of solutions for simple cases, for more see here  [Ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution).
Also for small random tree networks, see [this paper "Variability of collective dynamics in random tree networks of strongly coupled stochastic excitable elements"](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.98.052303)